# Having Errors When Submitting App to iTunes

Tags: xcode, macos, itunes

I'm new to this site and also new to making apps. I made an app not too long ago and am currently trying to submit it to the app store. Now I've already purchases my license along with created the certificates for the app. There is no errors in the xcode testing, yet I'm running into these errors when submitting the app to iTunes.

I took a screen shot of the 4 errors I'm having, here they are http://i237.photobucket.com/albums/ff234/pro_street427/ScreenShot2013-08-20at124339AM.png

Comment: have you created certificate for distribution yet?

Comment: Yes I did create distribution certificate.